# Rails - Do I need to do perform_later if using 3rd Party Mailing API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand if I need to have an Active Job (with Sidekiq or another service) and manage sending emails with perform_now or perform_later if I'm using a 3rd party emailing service like SendGrid or MailGun.

My thought is that the API call to the 3rd Party service is the only thing my server will be doing, and then once the request is made, the remainder of the task is within SendGrid's server - therefore, my website can continue its work. What would the benefit of having perform_later be with 3rd Party API?

Comment: The benefit is that the web thread does not have to perform the http request and can send the response faster. Wether or not its worth the additional complexity is hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `perform_later` will be the better option. I would suggest you to look at `perform_async` in sidekiq library. Also beware of errors and memory management when you are performing threads (3rd party API calls) in the background.